# Creation and annihilation operators in coordinate space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, harmonic-oscillator

I am trying to express the creation and annihilation operators of a single quantum harmonic oscillator in coordinate space. The problem is that, when I use $P \to -i\hbar d/dx$, I get $a=a^\dagger$:

$$a=\left(\frac{m \omega}{2 \hbar}\right)^{1 / 2} X+i\left(\frac{1}{2 m \omega \hbar}\right)^{1 / 2} P \\
= \left(\frac{m \omega}{2 \hbar}\right)^{1 / 2} X + \hbar \left(\frac{1}{2 m \omega \hbar}\right)^{1 / 2} \frac{d}{dx}.$$

Since all coefficients are real and $X$ is Hermitian, it follows that $a^\dagger = a$. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: $d/dx$ is not Hermitean, but anti-Hermitean. The second piece of the last line takes a minus sign when you do the conjugate.

Comment: A particular form of operators $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$ depends also on the scalar product definition.

Answer (score 1):

Note that :
$$\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^\dagger=-\frac{d}{dx}$$

$$a=(\cdots )X+(\cdots )\frac{d}{dx}$$
$$a^\dagger=(\cdots )X-(\cdots )\frac{d}{dx}$$
As expected $a\not=a^\dagger$.

---

Edit: It's not a rigorous proof
$$P=P^\dagger $$
$$P\rightarrow -i\hbar \frac{d}{dx}$$
$$-i\hbar \frac{d}{dx}=\left(-i\hbar \frac{d}{dx}\right)^\dagger=+i\hbar\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^\dagger$$
$$\Rightarrow \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^\dagger=-\frac{d}{dx} $$

Comment: Thanks @Young Kindaichi. Could you explain to me though why $\left(\frac{d}{d x}\right)^{\dagger}=-\frac{d}{d x}$?

Comment: @Y2H Please find the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Let $D:=d/dx$. I'll give another proof $D^\dagger=-D$. using indefinite integrals (over an unstated space, such as $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb R^3$):$$\langle u|D^\dagger|v\rangle=\overline{\langle v|D|u\rangle}=\overline{\int v^\ast Dudx}=\int v Du^\ast dx=-\int u^\ast Dvdx=-\langle u|D^\dagger|v\rangle,$$where the penultimate $=$ uses integration by parts (its surface term is $0$ due to the at-infinity behaviours of $u,\,v,\,Du,\,Dv$ for $u,\,v$ both $L^2$-normalizable).